# Animate a circular deformity moving across the edge of an object

Tags: animation

Can we make a circular deformity move across a plane as a wave like those characters from Toy Story:

[image]

Can we make the same effect in blender between two planes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized how to make the effect. I made a spherical texture, then I made a displace modifier to the plane, I selected the spherical texture, and I changed texture coordinate to an empty object. I changed the direction of displace modifier to X. Then I moved the empty object along the edge and it worked. I'll upload a GIF to illustrate This. 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the *Wave Modifier*.

1. Subdivide the plane a bit (5-6 levels of *Subdivision Modifier*)
2. Add the *Wave Modifier* and play with different values
3. Use the Video Sequencer slider to preview the animation

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not the same. The wave has to be moving across the edge of the plane to make the effect, not on the surface of the plane.

Comment: Well, then please add it to your original post :). It says "circular deformity across plane". And perhaps a different gif would illustrate it better.